# Practical common lisp - chapter 3

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I am new to programming and started with the practical common lisp book. My challenge is in the third chapter.

The function

```
(defun save-db (filename)
  (with-open-file (out filename
                   :direction :output
                   :if-exists :supersede)
    (with-standard-io-syntax)
      (print *db* out))))
```

When i go to the REPL and type `(save-db "c:/my-cds.db")`, I get the following:

Permission denied : "c:/my-cds.db"
Condition of type CCL::SIMPLE-FILE-ERROR

Could someone help me with the stage as I have been stuck for 2 days trying to understand what's wrong.

Thank you.

Comment: At the risk of stating the obvious, do you have permission to write directly to the root C:/ directory? That might be an administrator-only location.

Comment: I thought of that. But the laptop is mine and I am the only account on it which is the admin account.

Comment: That has nothing to do with permissions. User accounts can't access lots of things on the device, to prevent accidental destruction of important files. If you open Windows Explorer, can you make a new text file in `C:\` without privilege escalation? If it pops up with a User Account Control prompt, then the answer is no.

Comment: Hi Silvio, let me try this. SO:
1. open windows explorer,
What do you mean by make a new text file in C:?

Comment: Right click in the blank space. There should be a "New File" option or something. Try to make a new file. Or, alternatively, go to Notepad and try to save to the root `C:\` directory.

Comment: Blimey. You are right. Didn't let me.

Comment: It's a safety feature, protecting you from yourself. I'm on Linux, and the same protections exist here. Just work in `C:\Users\Whatever\Documents` instead and you should be fine.

Comment: Thank you. Your last suggestion I didn't quite understand. How will working in C:\Users\Whatever\Documents help me with the lisp issue? And could you please explain what you mean by "work in". I tried changing the directory in the save-db function but it still didn't work.

Comment: Rather than passing `C:/my-cds.db` as the argument to `save-db`, pass a path to your `Documents` folder, which is a user-level directory and won't have the same permissions issues, since there's nothing system-critical in your Documents folder. You don't need to change your Lisp code at all, just the input path you call it with

Comment: Is that file open in another process? Or the same one?  Are you in the middle of debugging another error, in context where the code being debugged has that file open?

Comment: try (merge-pathnames "sav.db" (user-homedir-pathname))

Comment: You might also want to try the book: [COMMON LISP: A Gentle Introduction to Symbolic Computation](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~dst/LispBook/book.pdf).  Answers to the exercises are in the back of the book.

Answer (score 3):

As discussed in the comments, this is just the operating system protecting you from accidentally damaging your system. Even on a single-user system, the OS won't let ordinary user accounts modify system directories, including the root of the main drive.

In your case, since you're just testing things, I recommend simply working in your `Documents` folder, which is probably `C:\Users\<YourName>\Documents`, and you shouldn't run into permissions issues.

If you really do need to modify `C:\`, you'll need to run your program as an administrator. On Linux, that's just `sudo`. On Windows, I believe you just run the command line as administrator by right-clicking it and hitting "Run as Administrator".

Comment: Thank you. I'll try that now.  

C:\Users\gName\Documents\my-cds.db

Edit: I tried it and it said:

"C" is not a defined logical host
   [Condition of type SIMPLE-ERROR"

Comment: `sudo` is a razor blade in the hands of not just sys admin novices. Easier to run code as a regular user maybe even inside some Virtual Machine than restore operating system. Also WSL2 may help to isolate consequences of errors from the working machine. Whatever you do: back up your code and settings on i.e. Github

Comment: You'll need to use a file syntax which CCL uses/supports on Windows.

Comment: @RainerJoswig could you kindly explain what you mean? I am new to all these.

Answer (score 2):

I use CCL on Windows. The Tankan application for learning Japanese characters is built using CCL.

This complete program writes the file successfully:

```lisp
(defvar *db* 42)

(defun save-db (filename)
  (with-open-file (out filename
                   :direction :output
                   :if-exists :supersede)
    (with-standard-io-syntax)
      (print *db* out)))

(save-db "c:\\Users\\kaz\\dbfile.lisp")
```

I get a file containing `42`.

It also works with single forward slashes: `"c:/Users/..."`.

With single backslashes, I get that problem that CCL's `parse-namestring` function tries to interpret the path as having a logical host name. Same error message that you saw.

I also get a permission error if I just use `"c:/dbfile.lisp"`.

Note that the doubled backslashes are just an escaping notation:

```
CCL is free software.  It is distributed under the terms of the Apache
Licence, Version 2.0.
? (length "\\")
1
? (length "\\a")
2
? (length "/a")
2
```

We can read a normal-looking path from the user, e.g. using `read-line`. When CCL prints that back to us as a string object, it adds the escapes:

```
> (read-line)
c:\Users\kaz\dbfile.lisp
"c:\\Users\\kaz\\dbfile.lisp"
NIL
```

They are not part of the data, just like the `"` quote characters are not.